# Sort categories by amount of entries

Tags: channel-entries, categories

When using `{exp:channel:categories}` to list categories, is it possible to sort the list by the number of entries each category has associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make use of [GWcode Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) which is an excellent free addon where you can simple do something like this:

```
{exp:gwcode_categories entry_count="yes" orderby="entry_count" sort="desc"}

    {cat_name} ({entry_count})

{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Where in this example I'm ordering by the entry count (descending) and also outputting the entry count if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sql with Query module:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT count(exp_category_posts.entry_id) AS total_entries, exp_categories.cat_id, exp_categories.cat_name, exp_categories.cat_url_title 
FROM exp_category_posts 
LEFT JOIN exp_categories ON exp_categories.cat_id=exp_category_posts.cat_id 
WHERE exp_categories.group_id=1 
GROUP BY cat_id 
ORDER BY count(entry_id) DESC"}

Total Number of entries = {total_entries}, Category ID = {cat_id}, Category Name = {cat_name}, Category URL Title = {cat_url_title}
<br />&nbsp;<br />

{/exp:query}
```

You need to update the category group id in WHERE condition (group_id=1) and ORDER BY either DESC or ASC.

With the above query, you can get other info like total number entries in a particular category, category name, category id and category url title.

I hope, it would help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bhashkar. I've gone with the GWcode Categories which seems a little simpler.

Comment: @Sam, I looked at this plugin and it seems much simpler :) .